# Can this be converted to a list comprehension?

Tags: python

The below function returns a list of words from a text file at a URL:

```
def fetch_words():
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
        story_words = []
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
    return story_words
```

I'm interested to see if this can be converted into an equivalent list comprehension. I've tried:

```
with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
     return [word for word in line.decode('utf-8').split() 
             for line in story]
```

but it errors with "unresolved reference 'line'".  It looks like I'm misunderstanding how nested list comprehensions work, can someone explain?

Comment: Easily, but I recommend using `requests`: `story_words = [w for line in requests.get('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt').text.splitlines() for w in line.split()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a list comprehension has two loops, they have to be in the same order as if they are for statements:

```
with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
    return [
        word 
        for line in story
        for word in line.decode('utf-8').split() 
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is slightly wrong, try this:

```
return [word for line in story for word in line.decode('utf-8').split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, I recommend using the [**`requests`**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) module:

```
story_words = [
    word 
    for line in requests.get('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt').iter_lines() 
    for word in line.decode('utf-8').split()
]
```

No context manager is required.

---

If the data you're reading in is reasonably small, you can use

```
story_words = [
    word 
    for line in requests.get('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt').text.splitlines()
    for word in line.split()
]
```